# perl regex "\w" does not accept "$"

Tags: regex, perl

So I have a regex that only wants to look for 2 words - just one word on a line will error, more than three words will kick it out and give me a line number (which is what I want).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings 
use strict 

open( my $filehandle ,"<", "/tmp/compare.cleartxt.tmpusers" ) || die "cant access the file" ;
    while (<$filehandle>) {
        if ($_ !~ /^\w+\s\w+$/) {
        print "LINE $., error on $_ " ;
        }
}
```

the problem is that some of these words contain "$" signs. 
like

```
LINE 700, error on ubs$iontest ubs$iontest
LINE 904, error on uho$jptest uho$jptest uho$jptest
LINE 1929, error on boa$jgb boa$jgb
LINE 2976, error on mitadel mitadel mitadel$001
LINE 3205, error on csfb csfb csfb$jpntest csfb$001 csfb$nytest
LINE 4762, error on mitsi$jgb2 mitsub$jgb2
LINE 6346, error on GOLDSTPTG GOLDSTPTG GOLDSTPTG
LINE 6660, error on jptest mizuho$jptest jptest
```

so I want to get rid of false positives like in line 700 or 1929, but keep errors like line 904.

I tired using this, but it presented alot more errors, like it printed every words with an underbar in it like "foo_bar"

```
if ($_ !~ /^[a-zA-Z$0-9]+\s[a-zA-Z$0-9]+$/)
```

Comment: What about `/^\S+\s\S+$/`

Comment: Have you considered stripping non-word characters before processing?

Comment: Replace `\w` with `[\w$]` (you might need to escape `$` as `\$` but I don't think that's the case).

Answer (score 4):

`\w` doesn't match `$` because `$` isn't considered a word character.

It looks like what you want to match, in Perl terms, is *either* a word character *or* a `$` character.

Try replacing `\w` by `[\w\$]`. (You need to escape the `$` so it doesn't treat `$]` as a variable reference.)

If you want to match sequences of non-whitespace characters, `\S` will match any single non-whitespace character. That includes all word characters and `$`; it also includes other punctuation characters.

I just noticed something else you wrote in your question:

> I tired using this, but it presented alot more errors, like it printed
>   every words with an underbar in it like "foo_bar".

Perl's definition of a "word character" is:

> alphanumeric plus "_", plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks

so the underscore `_` *will* be treated as a word character. It sounds like you want to match letters and `$`, but not `_`. What about digits? Other punctuation? Accented and non-Latin letters?

Once you specify *exactly* what you want to match, it will be much easier to construct a regular expression that will do the job.

See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or try `perldoc perlre` for more information on Perl's regular expressions.

Comment: Downvoter: There was an error in the initial version of this answer (which you might have pointed out). I believe it's correct now. Please look again if you happen to see this comment.

Comment: Are perl regex's unique in requiring the `$` to be escaped within a character class?

Comment: @hwnd: No, but text within `/.../` does have variable interpolation applied to it. A quick experiment shows that `$s =~ /([\w$]*)/` produces a complaint "Unmatched [ in regex", but `$s =~ /([\w\$]*)/` works. Interesting that `$s =~ /foo$/` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @hwnd: Yes, you do have to escape `$`, to avoid it being parsed as the start of a variable name. And it's *per se* - it's Latin and means *of itself*, but I wonder what you meant by it here?

Comment: @KeithThompson: `/foo$/` is unambiguous. Because there is nothing following the dollar sign it can't be the start of a variable name.

Comment: @Borodin: I can easily imagine a language quite similar to Perl in which `/foo$/` is ambiguous because `$/` can be a variable name. But apparently the `/` matching the opening delimiter takes precedence. It makes sense, but it's not 100% obvious.

Comment: l you are imagining is a language where variables can be interpolated anywhere, so the *entire source* is scanned for identifiers *first*, before any parsing is done. Unfortunately that is a point at which no variables can yet have been defined so it's a pretty useless language. There is nothing to prevent a variable name from using whitespace characters, so you are also proposing that the compiler shoud treat `${the rest of the program including other dollars}` as a potential variable interpolation. So yes, it's 100% obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/^[\w$]+\s[\w$]+$/
```